# newFixedThreadPool doesn't execute from time to time

Tags: java, threadpool

I need the thread pool to run once every hour. However, it doesn't behave as expected. It executes for a couple hours and then stopped. And after a few hours, it started working again.

Each thread is to read and calculate about 2000 records from mongodb which i think is fast enough to finish within a few minutes.

How to fix this problem?

Scheduler

```
  val interval = 1 * 60 * 60
  actorySystem.scheduler.schedule(10.seconds, interval.second, actor, "AuditActor")
```

ThreadPool

```
int totleSize = 1000;
int preprocessedNumberOfData = 100;
int pageCount = totleSize / preprocessedNumberOfData;

ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(pageCount);
try {
   if (pool == null) {
    return;
}
for (int i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++) {
    Future<?> future = pool.submit(new task(xxx,i,xxxx,xxxx));
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    play.Logger.error(e.getMessage());
}finally{
    pool.shutdown();
}
```

Comment: How did you tell her to run once every hour? How long does a task take to complete?

Comment: I edited the question. Each thread is to read and calculate about 2000 records from mongodb which i think is fast enough to finish within a few minutes. And I defined a scheduler when the application is started.